# resolve a cell value inside single-quoted table name selection

Tags: google-sheets

I have sheets like `january` `february` `march`, which have a known arrangement of values. I also have the month names written out in row 6 in my master table (i.e. A6=`january`, B6=`february`) etc. I would like the corresponding cell in row 7 to contain the value from cell E2 in the table named above it, as just like `='january'!E2`. However, it does not seem that I can do something like `=A6!E2` to resolve the table name dynamically.

Is there a way to escape the single quotes or something, so that dynamic values can be used to select a table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try, in A7:

```
=indirect(A6&"!E2")
```

[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

Comment: thanks! that worked for me. Would it be possible to use cell anchors relative to A7 in the "!E2" part as well? as if it were `=A6!E$2`?